# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.8.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, .net-framework-version

I have a vsix project. I use commandtool and create files. I upgraded .net framework (4.6.1 to 4.7.2) and packages

[image: package list]

I run project, everything is ok. But I get error when I click Extension's button.
[image: error]

I checked error in XML file. Error description is

> Description: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, Version=16.8.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; or one of its dependencies

But there is package in References

Do you have any idea?

Best Regards

Answer (score 1):

When you upgraded to the newer version of Microsoft.VisualStudio.Threading, you upgraded to a version that's higher than what your Visual Studio is shipping with as a part of the platform. Although there are ways you could make your version now be the preferred version, the easiest answer is probably 'don't do that', since you're artificially limiting which versions of VS your extension could install onto.

Unless you had a specific reason to upgrade, you're probably best off leaving the version there.